# Join two mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have an array with two  Mongoid::Criteria

```
[#<Mongoid::Criteria
      selector: {"news_category_id"=>"1"},
      options:  {:sort=>[[:published_date, :desc]], :limit=>1},
      class:    News,
      embedded: false>
    , #<Mongoid::Criteria
      selector: {"news_category_id"=>"2"},
      options:  {:sort=>[[:published_date, :desc]], :limit=>1},
      class:    News,
      embedded: false>
    ]
```

How can I get one Mongoid::Criteria object from that array of criteria?

When that array rendered , it contains "Array of Array of json objects" and I want an array of json objects. (single merged array of json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array, which contains "**Array of Array of json objects**"  to make a "**Array of json object**" i have come up with the following solution

```
array_of_criteria.collect { |aoc| aoc.to_a}.flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
criteria1.concat(criteria2) #this worked for me.
```

Answer (score 1):

Criteria has a merge method http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Criteria#merge-instance_method

Comment: In my case it does't work. if I do `array.first.merge(array.second)` it returns second criteria object.

Comment: @suvankar Of course it does. You are trying to merge 2 criteria with the same selectors. You cannot have 1 document with 2 different `news_category_id`. Merge will basically perform an "and" on your different criteria